# opening file using java and appending

Tags: java

I am wondering why nothing is being written to my file. I have the file in my project space, anytime I open it, there is nothing there. I am essentially trying to write to a file, close it, then appened to it again. so on so forth.

```
public static void writeToFile(String name) throws IOException{

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myFile.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    out.println(name);
    fw.close();
}
```

in my main I am just calling the method with a random string in the parameter

Comment: Can you post your entire code?

Comment: flush and close the printwriter e.g out.flush() and out.close(), you are closing the filewriter only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding flush() before you close the file. PrintWriter does not have automatic flushing

Comment: PrintWriter has a constructor which takes in writer and a boolean for autoflush https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.Writer,%20boolean)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
FileWriter fWriter;
File mFile = new File("fully qualified file name");
try{
 fWriter = new FileWriter(mFile, true);
 fWriter.write("File content");
 fWriter.flush();
 fWriter.close();
 }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```